# Jenkins : Build Time and timestamps

Tags: jenkins, timestamp

My jobs build at the same time every day.
But I don’t know why some job took a long time.
Does anyone know why this happens?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NZ2e.png)

After that I thought of looking at the full log output from the console.
Confirm when something went wrong
But when clicking full log, not all logs are listed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPiMo.png)

Jenkins stored log does not show time.
Or is there any way to read timestamps file?

Comment: Do you have the [timestamper](https://plugins.jenkins.io/timestamper/).plugin installed?

Comment: Yes, I have. But the content is unreadable

Comment: Not sure how you define unreadble, but there are customization opions, system-wide and in build display; see the plugins page referenced. Pick elapsed time and see where the gaps are.